# MySQL fetch array adds duplicate values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[id] => 1
[1] => 778613c4344dbc9565c359c1154c6a18
[session] => 778613c4344dbc9565c359c1154c6a18
[2] => fn
[first_name] => fn
[3] => ln
[last_name] => ln
[4] => un
[username] => un
[5] => 016e6128e8ca9dda1b310c364d9b622c
[password] => 016e6128e8ca9dda1b310c364d9b622c
[6] => address
[email] => address
[7] => 100
[permission] => 100
[8] => 10
[year_level] => 10
[9] => 
[department] => 
[10] => Sample
[campus] => Sample
[11] => 0
[logo_url] => 0
)
```

After running this

```
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT session FROM users WHERE username='$cookie[username]' AND first_name='$cookie[first_name]' AND last_name='$cookie[last_name]' AND campus='$cookie[campus]' AND id='$cookie[id]'"))
```

Any ideas why it is duplicating like this? Thanks

EDIT: I think the primary key is doing this. Any idea on how to stop it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't specify a result type as a second parameter, [**`mysql_fetch_array()`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) will default to `MYSQL_BOTH` *(quoting)* :

> By using `MYSQL_BOTH` (default), you'll get an array **with both
> associative and number indices**.

If this is not what you want, you have to pass a second parameter to that function, to indicate what type of results you want.

For example, to only get an associative array with columns names as keys :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT session FROM users WHERE username='$cookie[username]' AND first_name='$cookie[first_name]' AND last_name='$cookie[last_name]' AND campus='$cookie[campus]' AND id='$cookie[id]'");
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

As a sidenote :

- Make sure you are escaping the variables you inject into your query, to prevent [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), using, for example, [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- Before using `mysql_fetch_array()`, you should test if `mysql_query()` was successful,
- And, especially for a new project, you should use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo), and not the old [`mysql_*`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions -- see [Choosing an API](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: -1 for repeating old nonsense. escaping has nothing to do with SQL Injections yet mindless escaping "values" will make injection quite possible.

Comment: Well, making sure data injected into SQL queries are *safe* has to do with SQL Injections; and escaping strings is a way of making sure those are *safe*; Still, I admit I could have added that the same idea should be applied for non-string values, like integers *(making sure they really contain integers, with `intval()` for instance)*

Comment: an old delusion again. escaping doesn't make data *"safe"*. it's merely a formatting. And surely you have to use it (for strings) not for whatever safety but just to keep your SQL consistent. Integers is not alone case, identifier is another example of complete and utter uselessness of escaping that was supposed to make your "values" "safe"

Comment: True that using escaping *(for strings)* is required so you get well-formed SQL *(in case those strings contain special characters, like SQL-strings-delimiters, of course)*; but I consider that helping with that goal is some kind of *safety*: afterall, you want your SQL queries to run properly ;-)

Comment: Well, my queries already running properly, thank you for your concern. However, this fact doesn't make your misleading note true nor helpful.

Comment: Well, too bad I didn't help you; still, glad I could help the OP :-)

Comment: it is not help, it is actually a disservice. Followed literally, your "helpful" answer will make an injection possible, quite contrary to your (unwanted) sermon. But I am glad that a few more rep points made you such happy.

Answer (score 1):

Try second parameter MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_NUM. MYSQL_BOTH is ued by default, returning with both numberic and field keys.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal MARTIN has already explained the reason behind it.

I'll tell you to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` It'll give you only the associated array. Numerical part will not be present.